# assigning data to existing column in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to assign data to a column of the data frame using for loop and a function but I got the common warning:

> "SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame"

I have a data frame and three columns of date(year, month and day) and now I want a new column which converts those three columns to one.

I am using a for loop to assign the new data to the new column.
I tried to use `copy()` and `deepcopy()` as you can see below but it does not work.

```
    for i in range(100008):
        df.new_col[i]=convert(df.year[i],df.mounth[i],df.day[i])
```

what I tried instead of second line:

```
 df.new_col[i].copy()=convert(df.year[i],df.mounth[i],df.day[i]) 
 deepcopy(df.new_col[i]) =convert(df.year[i],df.mounth[i],df.day[i])
```

I expected my code to assign the values to the column and it does(as I interrupted the kernel and called the df) but it takes many hours to do this. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Please, when asking a question, remember to show the relevant part. A few lines of your starting dataframe, the expected result, and the relevant parts of your code (for example, the `g_to_j` function). So we can help better: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `for` loop, use the pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method, which is much faster.

If I understand correctly your code, you want something like this:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(convert2, axis=1)
```

where `convert2` is defined like:

```
def convert2(x):
    return convert(x['year'], x['month'], x['day'])
```

This is because, when passing a function to `apply`, the function must take as its argument a row or a column (a row in this case, since `axis=1`) of the dataframe.

Alternatively, instead of defining `convert2`, you can use a `lambda` function:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x : convert(x['year'], x['month'], x['day']), axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you, I tried the lambda function and it worked.
(I changed "g_to_j" to "convert", "comments" to "df" and 'jal_col" to "new_col" in case you wanted to edit your answer for others)